# Как написать запрос собирающий данные из нескольких таблиц на LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Надо же и мне побыть в роли [во]просителя...
Нужна помощь в написании запроса на LINQ.

Дословно:

> Найдите с использованием LINQ to Object для каждого аэропорта количество рейсов, в которых он является аэропортом вылета (FromAirportId) с 01.01.2020 р. по 31.12.2020 р. (список объектов с данными AirportId, AirportNam, FlightCount). Отсортируйте по количеству вылетов. Какой фрагмент кода надо вписать в строке 48?

Код — вот он:

```
namespace Application
{
    public class Airport // аеропорт
    {
        public int AirportId { get; set; }
        public string AirportName { get; set; }
    }
    public class Airplane //літак
    {
        public int AirplaneId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAirplane { get; set; } //дата виробництва
    }
    public class Flight //рейс
    {
        public int FlightId { get; set; }
        public int AirplaneId { get; set; }
        public int FromAirportId { get; set; } //аеропорт вильоту
        public int ToAirportId { get; set; } //аеропорт призначеня
        public DateTime FlightDate { get; set; } //lдата рейсу
        public int Passengers { get; set; } //кількість пасажирів
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var airports = new List<Airport>(){
                new Airport {AirportId = 1, AirportName = "Бориспіль"},
                new Airport {AirportId = 2, AirportName = "Charles de Gaulle"},
                new Airport {AirportId = 3, AirportName = "Schiphol"},
                new Airport {AirportId = 4, AirportName = "El Prat"}
            };
            var airplanes = new List<Airplane>(){
                new Airplane {AirplaneId = 10, DateAirplane = new DateTime(2000, 5, 25)},
                new Airplane {AirplaneId = 20, DateAirplane = new DateTime(2002, 10, 25)},
                new Airplane {AirplaneId = 30, DateAirplane = new DateTime(1989, 12, 30)}
            };
            var flights = new List<Flight>(){
                new Flight {FlightId =  100, AirplaneId  = 10, FromAirportId = 1, ToAirportId = 2, FlightDate = new DateTime(2020, 5, 25), Passengers = 150},
                new Flight {FlightId =  200, AirplaneId  = 10, FromAirportId = 1, ToAirportId = 3, FlightDate = new DateTime(2020, 6, 25), Passengers = 100},
                new Flight {FlightId =  300, AirplaneId  = 10, FromAirportId = 2, ToAirportId = 1, FlightDate = new DateTime(2020, 5, 26), Passengers = 95},
                new Flight {FlightId =  400, AirplaneId  = 20, FromAirportId = 1, ToAirportId = 3, FlightDate = new DateTime(2020, 8, 26), Passengers = 155},
                new Flight {FlightId =  500, AirplaneId  = 20, FromAirportId = 3, ToAirportId = 1, FlightDate = new DateTime(2020, 8, 27), Passengers = 132}
            };

            var query =  ???????????????


            foreach (var x in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.AirportId + " " + x.AirportName + " " + x.FlightCount);
            }

}
}
}
```

В строке 48 куча вопросительных знаков.

Пока что вышло — через одно место (лямбда-функцию), что уже на троечку. Но как получить имя аэропорта, так и не понял. В SQL можно собирать запросы из нескольких таблиц, а тут вроде нет?

Еще при этом так и не добавить аэропорт без вылетов вообще... :(

```
var query = from a in airports 
    join g in flights on a.AirportId equals g.FromAirportId
    where g.FlightDate.Year == 2020
    group g by g.FromAirportId into q
    orderby q.Count(), q.Key
    select new { AirportId = q.Key, 
                 AirportName = airports.Find(x=>x.AirportId == q.Key).AirportName, 
                 FlightCount = q.Count() };
```

Comment: Задание выглядит достаточно тривиальным. Вы можете его как-то конкретизировать, чтобы ответ был не *"почитать учебник и правила формирования запросов LINQ"*? А то граничит с *"вот мое задание, сделайте за меня все спасибопожалуйста"*

Comment: @Kromster Именно. После чтения учебника я так и не понял, как вытащить в запросе имя аэропорта (как вытащить в результаты разные поля из двух таблиц, а не одной). Свои труды я изложил, как видите, я не прошу делать за меня все задание :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно группировать не по `g.FromAirportId`, а по аэропортам `a`. Тогда можно записать ваш LINQ запрос так:

```
var query = from a in airports
            join g in flights on a.AirportId equals g.FromAirportId
            where g.FlightDate.Year == 2020
            group g by a into q
            orderby q.Count(), q.Key.AirportId
            select new
            {
                AirportId = q.Key.AirportId,
                AirportName = q.Key.AirportName,
                FlightCount = q.Count()
            };
```

---

**UPD.** Для выборки в результат аэропортов без подходящих под условие вылетов нужно `join` заменить на [`left join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins):

```
...
join f in flights on a.AirportId equals f.FromAirportId into gj
from g in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
...
```

В этом случае условие `where` придется убрать, иначе мы все же отбросим записи аэропортов без вылетов из группирующей выборки. Тогда фильтрующе условие можно, например, поместить в `Count()`. Весь запрос будет выглядеть так:

```
Func<Flight, bool> flightDateIn2020 = x => x?.FlightDate.Year == 2020;
// условие поиска вынес в предикат, чтобы не дублировать код в запросе в двух местах

// плохое решение из-за фильтрации в 2х местах!
// ниже есть исправленное
var query = from a in airports
            join f in flights on a.AirportId equals f.FromAirportId into gj
            from g in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            group g by a into q
            orderby q.Count(flightDateIn2020), q.Key.AirportId
            select new
            {
                AirportId = q.Key.AirportId,
                AirportName = q.Key.AirportName,
                FlightCount = q.Count(flightDateIn2020)
            };
```

---

**UPD 2 (убрал использование предиката):**
Выполнять фильтрацию по `flightDateIn2020` дважды всё же плохо, поэтому лучше сначала сделать выборку с фильтрацией, а потом уже отсортировать данные без повторной фильтрации:

```
// неотсортированный результат:
var query = from a in airports
            join f in flights on a.AirportId equals f.FromAirportId into gj
            from g in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            group g by a into q
            select new
            {
                AirportId = q.Key.AirportId,
                AirportName = q.Key.AirportName,
                FlightCount = (from c in q
                               where c?.FlightDate.Year == 2020
                               select c).Count()
            };

// отсортированный результат:
var orderedQuery = from a in query
                   orderby a.FlightCount, a.AirportId
                   select a;
```

Или то же самое в один запрос:

```
var query = from x in
               (from a in airports
                join f in flights on a.AirportId equals f.FromAirportId into gj
                from g in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                group g by a into q
                select new
                {
                    AirportId = q.Key.AirportId,
                    AirportName = q.Key.AirportName,
                    FlightCount = (from c in q
                                   where c?.FlightDate.Year == 2020
                                   select c).Count()
                })
            orderby x.FlightCount, x.AirportId
            select x;
```

Comment: Спасибо! А если я захочу еще и 0 для аэропорта без вылетов добавить, тогда как?

Comment: Тогда нужно обычный join переделать в left join: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins

Comment: Только в этом случае нужно и условие проверки года вылета "спустить" в `Count()`. Применив `where` мы сразу же отбросим записи аэропортов без вылетов из группирующей выборки.

Comment: Что-то не получается у меня это сделать... Не могли бы вы добавить код в ответ? Да и если я `where` выброшу ("отправить его в `Count()`" я не смог), то у аэропорта с отсутствием вылетов выводит 1...

Comment: Отредактировал ответ.

Comment: Мда, это я бы точно не додумался...

Comment: @Harry дошли руки переписать запрос с фильтрацией только в одном месте. Отредактировал ответ. Так будет корректнее.

Comment: А вот вложенных вопросов я при поиске вообще не нашел :) Спасибо еще раз!